# SQL Querying of Data by grouping with only one main variable(Store) and finding the percentage of customers in other variable

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Tables - Store

| Stores | Date | Customer_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2020 | 1111 |
| C | 01/01/2020 | 1111 |
| F | 02/01/2020 | 1234 |
| A | 02/01/2020 | 1111 |
| A | 02/01/2020 | 2222 |

Tables - Customer

| Customer_ID | Age_Group | Income_Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 26-30 | Low |
| 1234 | 25 and below | Mid |
| 2222 | 31-60 | High |

I want to know how I can get this output.

| Stores | Age_Group | Percentage_by_Age | Income_Level | Percentage_By_Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 25 and below | 10 | Low | 80 |
| A | 25 and below | 10 | Mid | 10 |
| A | 25 and below | 10 | High | 10 |
| A | 26 - 30 | 42 | Low | 15 |
| A | 26 - 30 | 42 | Mid | 65 |
| A | 26 - 30 | 42 | High | 20 |
| A | 31 - 60 | 48 | Low | 30 |
| A | 31 - 60 | 48 | Mid | 50 |
| A | 31 - 60 | 48 | High | 20 |

I am using SQL to query from different tables.
First I need to aggregate the number of customers by stores, then in each store, I want to find out how many customers visited Store A in a particular age group(25 and below), and how many of them are in which income level.

May I know how I can go about solving this query?

Thanks.

My current solution/thought process

```
SELECT 
    stores AS Stores,
    Age_Group AS Age,
    Income_Level AS Income
    COUNT(DISTINCT(Customer_ID)) AS Number_of_Customers
FROM tables JOIN tables....
GROUP BY Stores, Ages, Income;
```

And then manually calculating the percentages.
But it doesn't seem right.
Is there a way to produce an example output table using just SQL?

Comment: `I am using SQL to query from different tables.` Where are the other tables , the datas which produced the expected result?

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have added an example table.

Comment: The data you provided can't produce the expected result . How do you calculate `Percentage_by_Age` or `Percentage_By_Income`

Comment: Instead of COUNT(DISTINCT(Customer_ID)), I wanted to do this --> (COUNT(DISTINCT(CUSTOMER_ID))/ COUNT(*)) * 100 AS Percentage, but I realized that I cannot do that.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, [Common Table Expressions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax) can be used . You can use below code to get the expected output.

```
 WITH
 data_for_percent_by_income AS (
 SELECT
   COUNT(customer_id) AS cus_count_in_per_income_level_and_agegrp,
   Age_group AS age_g,income_level AS inc_lvl
 FROM
   `project.dataset.Customer2`
 WHERE
   customer_id IN (
   SELECT customer_id
   FROM
     `project.dataset.Store5`
   WHERE stores='A')
 GROUP BY
   Age_group,income_level),tot_cus_in_defined_income_level AS (
 SELECT
   COUNT(customer_id) AS cus_count_in_per_income_level,Age_group AS ag
 FROM
   `project.dataset.Customer2`
 WHERE
   customer_id IN (
   SELECT
     customer_id
   FROM
     `project.dataset.Store5`
   WHERE stores='A')
 GROUP BY
   Age_group),
 tot_cus_storeA AS(
 SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS tot_cus_in_A
 FROM
   `project.dataset.Customer2`
 WHERE customer_id IN (
   SELECT customer_id
   FROM
     `project.dataset.Store5`
   WHERE stores='A') ),
 final_view AS(
 SELECT
   ROUND(cus_count_in_per_income_level_and_agegrp*100/cus_count_in_per_income_level) AS p_by_inc,
   age_g,inc_lvl
 FROM
   data_for_percent_by_income
 INNER JOIN
   tot_cus_in_defined_income_level
 ON
   data_for_percent_by_income.age_g=tot_cus_in_defined_income_level.ag )
SELECT
 stores,tot_cus_in_defined_income_level.ag AS age_group,income_level,
 ROUND(cus_count_in_per_income_level*100/tot_cus_in_A) AS percentage_by_age,
 p_by_inc AS percentage_by_income
FROM
 tot_cus_in_defined_income_level,tot_cus_storeA,`project.dataset.Customer2`,`project.dataset.Store5`
INNER JOIN
 final_view
ON
 age_group=final_view.age_g AND income_level=final_view.inc_lvl
WHERE
 tot_cus_in_defined_income_level.ag = Age_group AND stores='A'
GROUP BY
 stores,percentage_by_age,age_group,income_level,percentage_by_income
ORDER BY Age_group
```

I have attached the screenshots of the input table and output table.

Customer Table

[image]

Store Table

[image]

Output Table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    s.Stores AS Stores,
    c.age_group AS Age,
    a.income_level AS Affluence,
    CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT c.Customer_ID) AS numeric)*100/SUM(CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT c.Customer_ID) AS numeric)) OVER(PARTITION BY s.Stores ) AS Perc_of_Members
```

This is what I did in the end.